# Issue installing BootCamp drivers for Windows 10

Tags: audio, drivers, windows-10, macbook-pro, boot-camp

I installed Windows 10 on my 15" Retina Macbook Pro. Once installed, I attempted to install the BootCamp drivers but it keeps getting hung up on the Realtek audio driver. I even left it overnight thinking it was just really slow but still no luck.

Anyone have trouble with the install and/or know what could be the issue here?

Specifics:

- BootCamp 6
- 2013 15" Retina MacBook Pro
- OS X El Capitan
- Realtek Driver 2.84

I attempted to install the drivers individually, boot the BootCamp launcher that allows you to reboot into OS X and the Apple Touch Pad driver is not installed properly. The touchpad does not allow for scroll or right click.

Comment: We need more specifics.  What version of Bootcamp?  What version of OS X?  What year is the Macbook specifically?  Have you tried to supply different Realtek drivers?

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks. Updated with all the info I knew.

Comment: What build of Windows 10 are you using?  Update your question to reflect this information.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I had the same problem as well. The issue seems to be that the Bootcamp software is looking for the correct Realtek drivers, but can't find them so it just hangs. To fix it, manually install the [drivers from Realtek](http://www.realtek.com/downloads/downloadsCheck.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=24&PFid=24&Level=4&Conn=3&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false) while the Bootcamp setup is running. Then, go to Task Manager, find the Setup process, right click and press Go to details. Then find the RealtekSetup.exe process and kill that. Bootcamp setup will now skip that step and continue installing the rest of the drivers. And since you downloaded the realtek drivers manually, you now have those as well.

For more info see [this thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6567790) on apple discussion forms.

According to @Pi, it is unnecessary to download the Realtek drivers. Just kill the `RealtekSetup.exe` process, let the installation of the rest of the drivers complete, and then run this `RealtekSetup.exe` process from list of software included in the Bootcamp drivers. You can find this executable at `/BootCamp/Drivers/Realtek/RealtekProcess.exe`.

Comment: great Answer! didnt know, that you can stop one part of a setup via task manager :) thanks a lot!

Comment: Brad Frost for president!

Comment: You do not need to get the drivers from RealTek. You can install them directly from your Boot Camp USB stick.

Comment: Also, you can just simply kill the process (i.e. neither download them nor install them from the Boot Camp USB stick). I've just done that, and it has completed successfully. (I believe automatic updates will recover the drivers).

Comment: @Pi you can skip downloading the Realtek drivers, but you won't have them. The Bootcamp software will be unable to find the drivers. It might be the case that Windows 10 works without the drivers, as you have seen. If you want everything that the Bootcamp software *intended* to install, you will need to download Realtek drivers manually.

Comment: @BradFrost ok. But there is no need to download them. Going to /BootCamp/Drivers/Realtek on the thumb drive and executing RealtekSetup.exe correctly installs them. I've just done it right now and it works! So I would recommend anyone to terminate the process when it hangs, allow the Boot Camp install to complete, and then install the realtek driver as described.

Comment: @Pi, nice find! I modified the original answer to include this information.

Answer (score 0):

Brad Frost's answer seemed to work for many.
But when I killed (End Task) the process, the whole Bootcamp windows setup failed.
The solution that worked for me was to remove the Realtek folder from Bootcamp\Drivers and then run the Bootcamp setup. Then the complete setup was successful.
Then the Realtek audio drivers can be installed manually from the removed folder.

Answer (score 0):

I found the fix to this problem. I installed Win10 on my 15inch Macbook pro with bootcamp. I tried several times and bootcamp on windows hung up on Realtek installation each time. Follow these steps to fix:

1. Go to Bootcamp folder, find Realtek, and install manually (double click Realtek setup.
2. Go to Task Manager - Click details - find the Realtek task - end task (DO NOT END THE ENTIRE BOOTCAMP TASK)
3. Installation will continue
4. All is right in the world.

Answer (score 0):

First of all thanks to every1 for sharing your views,i have faced this very exact problem about installing realtek sound driver in bootcamp,every time bootcamp just hangs,and the only simple trick to this very annoying issue is to kill the realtek installation task by entering into your task manager,just kill the process and the bootcamp installation will b completed successfully and after that you can install the realtek driver manually by entering bootcamp folder and the problem is gone.Enjoy :)